# Possibilities to handle rate limit in Scala

Tags: scala, api, rate-limiting, restrict

What are the possibilities of handling rate limit in Scala.
I'm  playing with http4s and scala to perform basic requests to a REST API.
knowing that the request returns information about rate limit (totalRateLimit, remainingRateLimit, RestRateLimitAfter).

I need suggestions based on simple solutions that does not demand really advanced knowledge of scala to perform this.

I'm using http4s. I'm not using any concurrency model yet. I am open to suggestions. I have a single server instance.

Comment: How are you doing the requests? Which library are you using? which concurrency model are you already using or willing to use?

Comment: Also: do you have a single server instance or do you have a horizontally scaled application, where rate state should be shared between several instances.

Comment: I edited the question!! can you please check it out @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: @mateuszKubuszok I didn't get the question related to the shared state

Comment: if you have a single instance, guava rate limit may be the easiest solution. otherwise something like redis probably

Comment: @pedrorijo91 i want a functional scalla based solution though

Comment: well, rate limit needs to keep state, so it's not functional. just delegate rate limit into the load balancer. https://ayushworks.github.io/ratelimiter4s/

Comment: I will chheck this library in depth, I have read about rate limit and I came across some synchronized type in scala , but I didn't really seized the idea. (I"m still learning and improving in scala ... so)

Comment: @MarEs if you are using **http4s** you already have two concurrency models: **IO** and **fs2.Stream**. Anyways it seems you already got a suggestion for a strong library. Another approach is to enqueue all petitions and have a fixed amount of workers reading from the queue and executing the petitions.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you , I got anothersuggestion which is upperbound Library https://github.com/SystemFw/upperbound if you got to choose between it and ratelimiter4s which one would you go for ?

Comment: @MarEx I actually haven't used any of those so I do not have any opinion, do a little poc with both and see which one do you like the most.

Answer (score 0):

It may a simple solution to take advantage of guava Ratelimiter to perform your request.

```
https://www.baeldung.com/guava-rate-limiter
```